# Get current memory usage of WKWebView by code?

Tags: ios, memory, wkwebview

Is there a way to get `current memory usage` of WKWebView by code?

I know that there's a delegate for `func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView)`

But it's kind of too late.
What I need is pre crash.